# Что использовать для создания книги?

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы в левом меню DrawerNavigation отображались главы, а на экране текст с пролистыванием между экранами, как в обычных читалках. Также нужна возможность изменения размера шрифта.
Так вот вопрос, какие элементы разметки использовать для этого не пойму? Чтобы реализовать прокрутку текста

Comment: Как то очень путано звучит ваш вопрос, что именно вам нужно сделать?

Comment: @Valeriy ну то есть есть текст, например, в txt формате. Нужно чтобы он распределялся по экранам в зависимости от установленного размера текста. Чтобы можно было пролистывать влево-вправо как бы страницы (как во многих приложениях читалках). Не могу сообразить, каким образом реализовать это

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит начать отсюда:
https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ

В нем страницы пролистываются как вы хотите, но мне такая реализация не по душе, мне больше нравится реализация пролистывания в EBook Droid Reader.

Не знаю на сколько это будет правильно, но на крайняк можно было бы разбить текст на страницы и показывать их при помощи "ViewPager-a", хотя это больше похоже на извращение, но будут прогружаться только три страницы, а это уже меньше будет хавать ресурсов, да и анимацию перелистывания будет легко пристроить.

Как бы по факту если человек уже выбрал шрифт то он его менять не будет, соответственно мы будем разбивать текст только первый раз и дальше уже будем хранить обработанный вариант.

По поводу глав, думаю самое лучшее парсить содержание и хранить их в паре: заголовок, страница, будет достаточно легко сделать переходы.